# How to Select resources with specific property in dbpedia with Sparql Query?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia, apache-jena

I  have the query --

```
PREFIX rdf:    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbo:    <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

#select count(DISTINCT ?instance)  # The number of suitable instances
#select DISTINCT ?instance ?type  # Full Ground-truth dataset
select DISTINCT ?instance ?domain ?range ?subClassOf  # Full Algorithm input dataset (sampling might be required)
where {
   ?instance rdf:type ?type;
             rdfs:domain ?domain;
             rdfs:range ?range;
             rdfs:subClassOf* ?subClassOf.
}
ORDER BY ?instance
```

-- which returns all the triples which have `type`, `domain`, and `range` properties. The resultset is like --

```
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/torqueOutput>  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#domain>  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/AutomobileEngine>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/torqueOutput>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/torqueOutput>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/torqueOutput>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#DatatypeProperty>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/torqueOutput>  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#range>  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/torqueOutput>  <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#wasDerivedFrom>  <http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/OntologyProperty:torqueOutput>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/torqueOutput>  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>  "torque output (Nm)"@en  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/displacement>  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#domain>  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/AutomobileEngine>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/displacement>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/displacement>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/displacement>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#DatatypeProperty>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/displacement>  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#range>  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/displacement>  <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#wasDerivedFrom>  <http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/OntologyProperty:displacement>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/displacement>  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>  "cilindrada (μ³)"@es  .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/displacement>  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>  "displacement (μ³)"@en  .
```

As you see, all the subjects are `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/......` but I would like to have the `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/....` as my subjects. Is there any way to have them?  My desired triples would look like this:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Otto_Georg_Thierack>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Otto_Georg_Thierack>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Otto_Georg_Thierack>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Otto_Georg_Thierack>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://schema.org/Person>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Otto_Georg_Thierack>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Erich_Wasicky>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Erich_Wasicky>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Erich_Wasicky>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent>  .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Erich_Wasicky>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://schema.org/Person>  .
```

Comment: You are mixing up different entities in your query: instances are asserted to classes via rdf:type, properties do have domain and range, and classes are related to others via `rdfs:subClassOf`.

Comment: I think your query needs major changes for your desired result.

Entities like `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Otto_Georg_Thierack>` do not have `rdfs:domain` nor `rdfs:range`, though they will typically have `rdf:type`.

Perhaps you should give us a better idea of what you're trying to achieve, and why (as this looks rather like a homework assignment to me).